# AWS SDK - very big - 11MB. I want to use only the SimpleDB service

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I am using Amazon SimpleDB from a desktop java app. Thus my installer needs to ship the aws-sdk jar as well. The issue is, its 11mB and has a whole lot of classes for services that I will not use.

Is there an easy way of splitting up the sdk into smaller chunks. Like have all the common code into one jar. And all the service specific code into another jar?

Is there something that I could use out of the box? Or do I need to this myself after downloading the code?

I am using the typica library. But its not maintained anymore and is not compatible with the latest httpcomponents.

Comment: not exactly what you need, but keep this in mind: http://www.jcabi.com/jcabi-simpledb/

Comment: but this jcabi is wrapper of aws-sdk. So i need to ship aws-sdk jars and the jcabi jars. So it wont help my original problem. jar size.

Answer (score 9):

I had to work it out with the aws-sdk-code. I excluded a few packages from the pom.xml and the size reduced to 800kb.

```xml
<plugin> 
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.7</source>
    <target>1.7</target>
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/autoscaling/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/cloudformation/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/cloudfront/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/cloudfront_2012_03_15/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/cloudsearch/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/cloudtrail/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/cloudwatch/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/datapipeline/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/directconnect/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/dynamodb/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/ec2/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/elasticache/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/elasticbeanstalk/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/elasticloadbalancing/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/elasticmapreduce/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/elastictranscoder/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/glacier/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/identitymanagement/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/importexport/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/kinesis/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/opsworks/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/rds/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/redshift/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/route53/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/s3/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/securitytoken/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/simpleemail/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/sns/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/sqs/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/storagegateway/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/services/support/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/metrics/**</exclude>
        <exclude>com/amazonaws/auth/policy/resources/SQSQueueResource.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Also it needed to 3 dependencies alone for it to work

```xml
<properties>
        <jackson.version>2.1.1</jackson.version>
</properties>

 <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>

</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>

</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    <type>jar</type>

</dependency>
```

So in total it came out to less than 2MB. I was using typica and since this was a drop in replacement for it didn't increase my installer size at all.

Answer (score 0):

I did similar by using maven-shade-plugin's minimizeJar configuration. Instead of specifying user-specified filters which are time-consuming and error-prone, this plugin can be configured to automatically remove all classes of dependencies that are not used by the project, thereby minimizing the resulting uber JAR.

```html
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```