# Zip File too large to upload lambda

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, aws-lambda

I am trying to deploy a reactive web application to lambda. I am using terraform and aws SDK for development.

When I tried to mvn package and terraform apply I got the following error.

> ╷ │ Error: updating Lambda Function (next_travel_Products_BE) code:
> operation error Lambda: UpdateFunctionCode, https response error
> StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 97ac5a23-12ea-4d5b-b868-82f6f3b65db1,
> InvalidParameterValueException: Unzipped size must be smaller than
> 262144000 bytes │  │   with aws_lambda_function.guideserviceFunction,
> │   on main.tf line 92, in resource "aws_lambda_function"
> "guideserviceFunction": │   92: resource "aws_lambda_function"
> "guideserviceFunction" {

[image]

Seems like my zip file is too large. How can I reduce this size?

[image]

Here is the pom file of the project

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.siyum</groupId>
    <artifactId>guide_service_v4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Serverless Spring Boot 2 API</name>
    <url>https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container</url>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.11</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws.serverless</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-serverless-java-container-springboot2</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.28</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.565</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>shaded-jar</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.4</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>shade</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactSet>
                                        <excludes>
                                            <exclude>org.apache.tomcat.embed:*</exclude>
                                        </excludes>
                                    </artifactSet>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>assembly-zip</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <!-- don't build a jar, we'll use the classes dir -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>default-jar</id>
                                <phase>none</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>true</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <!-- select and copy only runtime dependencies to a temporary lib folder -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.2.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}${file.separator}lib</outputDirectory>
                                    <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.3.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>zip-assembly</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>single</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                                    <descriptors>
                                        <descriptor>src${file.separator}assembly${file.separator}bin.xml</descriptor>
                                    </descriptors>
                                    <attach>false</attach>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: No, it seems your *unzipped data* is too large: "Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda quotas:

Deployment package (.zip file archive) size

1. 50 MB (zipped, for direct upload)
2. 250 MB (unzipped)

Solutions:

1. Please ensure you are zipping only the executable jar file under `target/` folder.
2. Reduce the dependent packages, for example "aws-sdk" package size is around 11MB. For reducing the size please exclude the unnecessary package.
   [AWS SDK - very big - 11MB. I want to use only the SimpleDB service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043166/aws-sdk-very-big-11mb-i-want-to-use-only-the-simpledb-service)
3. If above solutions doesn't resolve your issue.Then, Containerise the java application and deploy it to lambda. Allowed image size is 10GB.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-image.html#java-image-instructions

Comment: Yeah, I wanted to use S3 for the service. I removed whole SDK and insert only the S3 SDK.